# Highlight matched string in loops

Tags: highlighting

I'm writing a loop to perform some interactive replacements on matched strings:

```
(while (search-forward-regexp "REGEXP" nil t)
  (read-char "Options:...")
  ; Replacements...
  )
```

and I need the matched string to be "temporarily" highlighted until the replacement has done (or skipped).

What is the best way to get this behaviour?

(I figure out something like this:

```
(while (search-forward-regexp "REGEXP" nil t)

  (push-mark (match-beginning 0))
  (let ((x (make-overlay (mark) (point))))
    (overlay-put x 'face '(:background "grey20")))

  (read-char "Options:... ")
  (remove-overlays (mark) (point))
)
```

but I'm pretty sure it is not the best choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the mark. Just use `(match-beginning 0)`.  You can always let-bind a variable to that, if you're worried about the match-data changing.

```el
(while (search-forward-regexp REGEXP nil t)
  (let* ((beg  (match-beginning 0))
         (xx   (make-overlay beg (point))))
    (overlay-put xx 'face 'YOUR-FACE)
    (read-char "Options:... ")
    (remove-overlays beg (point))))
```

---

`C-h f push-mark` tells you this, at the end:

> Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the wrong
>   purposes.  See the documentation of `set-mark` for more information.

And `C-h f set-mark` tells you this, at the end:

> Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the wrong
>   purposes.  The mark saves a location for the user's convenience.
>   Most editing commands should not alter the mark.
>   To remember a location for internal use in the Lisp program,
>   store it in a Lisp variable.  Example:
>
> ```
> (let ((beg (point))) (forward-line 1) (delete-region beg (point))).
> ```

Comment: More things to tell: (1) Use only overlays with some id (last two optional args of `remove-overlays`) otherwise you potentially remove overlays which are unrelated to your stuff. (2) Maybe wrap the setting of overlays in `unwind-protect` and put `remove-overlays` in the unwind forms else the overlays remain when the user quits. (3) It depends on the number of highlights whether overlays or text properties are preferable.

Comment: @Tobias The highlight is once at time. Also, I looked for a  variable for overlay settings... 'cause I figured out to let-bind it but I was not able to find it.